# High memory usage windows 2008

Tags: windows, sql-server, memory-usage

I have a Windows server with 32 GB RAM, which is running sqlserver and tomcat.

In resource monitor it show more than 95% memory usage, but when I searched in processes all process, each process is consuming less than 500 MB memory.

Below are some of the top memory usage process from server.

```
Tomcat7 (SYSTEM)       360 MB
sqlservr (SYSTEM)      328 MB
w3wp (NETWORK SERVICE) 302 MB
chrome (devel)         283 MB
svchost (SYSTEM)       266 MB
javaw (devel)          247 MB
......                 146 MB
Ssms (devel)           80 MB
NewRelic.ServerMonitor 69 MB
java (SYSTEM)          65 MB
...... (SYSTEM)        62 MB
explorer (devel)       54 MB
....... (devel)        49 MB
....... (SYSTEM)       40 MB
svchost                26 MB
....... (SYSTEM)       26 MB
WmiPrvSE               24 MB
services (SYSTEM)      9 MB
........ (devel)       6 MB
```

How do I find the process which is invisible in task manager but consuming all the memory?

Comment: Use VMMap and RAMMap from live.sysinternals.com. They give a much more detailed, granular picture of what's going on with both your physical and your virtual memory than Task Manager does.

Comment: This does not seem to be a production system, but a development system, because you are running chrome, SQL Server and IIS/Tomcat on the same machine, as well as SQL Server Management Studio. Development systems are off-topic here on serverfault.com

Comment: post some pictures of RAMMap (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, SQL Server grabs all the memory that it can, even if it's not listed in Task/Resource manager.